# can i make aloop inside a loop and both end at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

well i have a form data `object`:

```
  const formData = {
    type: [
      "text",
      "text", 
      "number", 
      "email",
      "text",
      "text", 
      "text", 
      "number"],
    div: [
      "col-6",
      "col-6",
      "col-6",
      "col-6",
      "col-12",
      "col-4",
      "col-4",
      "col-4",
    ],
  };
```

i wanted to make 2 loops so the output be like this

```
<div className="col-6">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div className="col-6">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
.
.
.
```

I've tried a nasted loop but I already know that the inner loop will end in the first outer loop

```
{formData.div.map((clsName) => (
  <div className={clsName}>
     {formData.type.map((type) => (
       <input type={type} />
     ))}
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Assuming, that the type and div properties always have arrays of the same length, you can easily do that within one loop.

Comment: Right, but not with `map`.  You'd use a counter, from 0 to length-1.

Comment: Is there a reason for that data structure? Wouldn't it make more sense to have something combined... `[{ type: 'text', div: 'col-6' }, ...]`

Comment: The way your structure is made is fundamentally incorrect. Generally, you would only use a nested loop for nested arrays. Your arrays are not nested. If they're two independent loops, use two loops. If they're dependent and the same length, just use one loop.

Comment: I would not describe what `map` does as a _loop_.  In fact, it is a functional iteration construct, and it's worth drawing a distinction between the behaviour of `map` vs the behaviour of a loop. For example, you can't `break` out of a map like you can with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to the map function is the index within the array, so you *could* use that index to pull the corresponding `type` entry, like this:

```js
{formData.div.map((clsName, index) => (
  <div className={clsName}>
    <input type={formData.type[index]} />
  </div>
))}
```

But there are a couple of potential problems, like having to be sure the `type` and `div` arrays are the same length.

I'd recommend that you instead change the shape of your input data to be an array of objects, instead of an object of arrays:

```js
const formData = [
  {
    type: 'text',
    div: 'col-6',
  },
  {
    type: 'text',
    div: 'col-6',
  },
  {
    type: 'number',
    div: 'col-6',
  }
]
```

This keeps the related info together and allows you to map over it much more intuitively:

```js
{formData.map((entry) => (
  <div className={entry.div}>
    <input type={entry.type} />
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a `key` prop to the `<div>`